# При подключении стилей в шаблоне django ошибка 404

Tags: django

На сайте используется django-pipeline. Статика разделена на статик приложения, проекта и выходную. Схема показана ниже:

- name_project

  - app

    - static

      - app

        - scss
  - static

    - scss
- static

  - css

В файле настроек:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1'
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR + "/static/",
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

В шаблоне стиль вызывается:

```
{% load pipeline %}
{% load staticfiles %}
..
{% stylesheet 'name_style' %}
..
```

При открытии страницы:
`GET /static/css/name_style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1670`

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А без django-pipeline статика отдаётся нормально?

Comment: Нет, при попытке посмотреть содержимое файла пишет 
Page not found

Comment: Значит проблема не в django-pipeline. Что у вас отвечает за отдачу статики, dev-сервер, nginx, что-то другое?

Comment: За статику отвечает Dev server

Comment: Покажите ваш urls.py

Comment: from django.conf.urls import include, url  
from django.contrib import admin  
  
urlpatterns = [  
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  
    url(r'^$', include('name_app.urls')),  
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш dev-сервер не знает как обрабатывать запросы к STATIC_URL. Надо добавить в urls.py несколько строк:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```